# Automorphism groups of fields

Tags: fields, galois-groups

Hi there,

is there a classification/characterization of fields **K** for which the automorphism group Aut(**K**) has  the property that |Aut(**K**)| < |**K**| (e.g. finite fields, the rationals and reals) ?
 What about the same question for real-closed fields **K** ? 
 Many thanks ...

Comment: What automorphisms? Do you mean $| \cdotp |$ =cardinaity?

Comment: General field automorphisms. And indeed, |.| = cardinality.

Comment: You might take a clue from vector space automorphisms over a prime field.  When that is large enough, there is a good chance the set of field automorphisms will also be large.  If so, the question will be which fields are smaller than the power sets of their generators, which can be turned into a pure set-theoretic issue.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.05.10

Comment: @Gerhard: Unfortunately, the reals have lots of vector-space automorphisms over the prime field $\mathbb Q$ but no nontrivial field automorphisms.  (I like to see things turn into set theory, but this one will need more work.)

Comment: The fields ${\mathbb{Q}}_p$ have only the identity automorphism, like the reals.

Comment: @Lubin: that's interesting, can you explain why?

Comment: If $K$ is finite with $|K|=p^n$ then $Aut(K)=Gal(K|\mathbb{F}_p)$ is cyclic of order $n$. Hence $|Aut(K)| < |K|$  in case of finite fields. 

Comment: This question is relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22897/fields-with-trivial-automorphism-group

Comment: Andreas, yes, but are there prime fields of larger than countable cardinality?  The suggestion is that above a certain cardinality, the answer will be that there are none in set theories with GCH.  However, I am  unsure, so I leave it as a conditional comment.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.05.10

Comment: Gerhard, I guess we are using the terminology "prime field" with different meanings.  To me, it means a field with no proper subfields, i.e., either the rationals or a finite field of prime order.  